# Check if data exist when using onChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to check if child data exists over a Firebase `DataReference` when using `observeChildEvent`? I'm using `onChildEventListener` to fill a `RecyclerView` on my application but during the data change, I show a `ProgressBar`. The problem appears when there's no data in the current query, so I never receive an event and I can't hide my progressBar.

Is there any way to achieve this without launch a previous `observeSingleValueEvent` with a `limit(1)` value to check in the `dataSnapshot` if there is available data?

Comment: Child event handlers only exist when a child exists, gets modified, gets removed, etc. There is no child event that fires when no child exists. Typically you'd handle that with a value listener.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Then is right check if the data exist with a SingleValueEvent before use a ChildEventListener?

Comment: I can't determine what is right for your use-case. But if you want to detect whether something exists, the normal way to do that is to attach a value listener to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [RxFirebase2](https://github.com/FrangSierra/Rx2Firebase) to work with Firebase, so I did a method to check if a `DatabaseReference` have childrens, using it together with RxJava to avoid use `OnChildEvents` when my reference have no childrens:

```
  public Single<Boolean> checkIfRefHaveAvailableChild(DatabaseReference databaseReference){
      final Query query = databaseReference.limitToFirst(MIN_RETRIEVE_DATA);
      return RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(query)
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .take(1)
         .map(dataSnapshot -> dataSnapshot.hasChildren())
         .single(false);
   }
```